# OSX cannot open the `chrome://` protocol by the `open` command

Tags: node.js, shell, google-chrome, node-debugger

when I try to edit

```
open "chrome://settings"
```

It says: The file /chrome:/settings does not exist.

```
open -a Google\ Chrome "chrome://settings"
```

also couldn't open the settings in chrome. seems the `open` command only could open the `http && https` protocol

In fact, I want to debug some Node code in Chrome Dev Tool, every time I run

```
node --inspect --debug-brk index.js
```

I must copy the debug link into Chrome to open the Dev Tool. I want to open it automatically. But the open command cannot it.

Comment: Can you try this out once?
open -a Google\ Chrome "chrome:////settings"

Comment: @NikhilMotiani doesn't worked. it shows `The file /chrome:/settings does not exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research. Seems Chrome doesn't allow such internal urls for security concerns. Accessing these internal pages, can't be accessed directly, even using `using window.location.replace("chrome://settings/")`

These involve either creating an extension, or changes the chrome profile for default/first page opened.

- Using Extension (credits @alvin-wong on superuser.com) https://superuser.com/questions/558672/open-chrome-and-launch-the-settings-page
- Changing Profile Settings and restoring them via script https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/2Tm8WHyf6y8/O7ZAGGfdBrMJ

Though these would solve your problem, but both of them are hacky way of doings things, and hence not advisable.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Very helpful.